# Creating a deck of Cards

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Okay, first off I have looked at various of the questions that were asked about creating a deck of Cards but every single one I looked was using the vector thing, I'm not sure how to write it, cause I have not taken that subject in class so I don't know how to apply it.

The `Card.H` and `Card.cpp` are all fine, no need to change a thing in them

I need help in `Deck.H` and `Deck.cpp`.

My `initialize()` function is not finished and I cant seem to know how to finish it and with the other methods in the Deck class I have not tried to write any of them  since I cant generate a deck of cards.

**CARD.H**

```
Class Card
{

    int m_face; 
    char m_suit;


public:

Card(int _face = 2 , char _suit = 3);

~Card();

int GetFace() const;
char GetSuit() const;

void SetFace(int _face);
void SetSuit(char _suit);

void Show() const;
}
```

**CARD.CPP**

```
#include "Card.h"
Card::Card(int _face, char _suit)
{

    m_face = _face;
    m_suit = _suit;
}

Card::~Card()
{

}
int Card ::GetFace() const
{
   return m_face;
}

char Card ::GetSuit() const
{
    return m_suit;
}

void Card::SetFace(int _face)
{
   m_face = _face;
}

void Card::SetSuit(char _suit)
{
   m_suit = _suit;
}

void Card::Show() const
{
   if (m_face == 11)
      cout << " J " << m_suit << endl;
   else if (m_face == 12)
      cout << " Q " << m_suit << endl;
   else if (m_face == 13)
      cout << " K " << m_suit << endl;
   else if (m_face == 14)
      cout << " A " << m_suit << endl;
   else
      cout << m_face << m_suit << endl;
}
```

**DECK.H**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Card.h"

Class Deck
{
    Card m_cards[52];

public:

    Deck();
    void Initialize();
    void Shuffle();
    bool Draw(Card& _card);
    void Clear();
    bool IsEmpty() const;
}
```

**DECK.CPP**

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include"Card.h"

void Deck::Initialize()
{
int count = 0;
    char Suits[] = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) //Suits
    {

        for (int F = 2; F < 14; ++F) //faces
        {
            m_cards[count].SetSuit(Suits[i]);
            m_cards[count].SetFace(F);

        }
    }

}

    void Deck::Shuffle()
{
}
    bool Deck::Draw(Card& _card
{
}
    void Deck::Clear()
{
}
    bool Deck::IsEmpty() const
{
}
```

Comment: Your question is? Your `initialize` seems complete for me. This should be in the constructor.

Comment: Use the _vector thing_! There's no point tackling memory management on your own in c++. It's just error prone, and you have many pitfalls to avoid. Any teacher telling anything different in a basic c++ course isn't worth their salary, and you should immediately quit that course.

Comment: my question is how can i finish my initialize function

Comment: I cant tell what is left?

Comment: @jafar in the constructor i call the Initialize function.

Comment: @M.Lugo Also note there's [`std::array<Cards,52>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) available nowadays. Probably best used in conjunction with an initializer list.

Comment: Learning how to use vector is more important than learning how to deal with a deck if cards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your Initialize function needs much more work.

Only 2 remarks:

1. You forgot a `++count` at the end of the inner for loop (now you're setting the same card every time).
2. As you wrote the inner for loop, the `F` variable will only be allowed to go up to 13 (because you used `< 14`).  This means your deck won't contain any aces ... most logical thing for me would be to use `<= 14` instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did that and i ran a test function which the teacher wrote in the solution that lets us know if the function works or not and im still not able to create the 52 Cards.

Comment: This is what The test thing looks when I run it                                                Testing Deck::Initialize Verifying 52 unique cards                                                
e:\full sail\pg2\pg2 project\card game\lab3_test.cpp(715): error: Failure in PG2_Lab3_Deck_Initialize: !memcmp(refDeck, deck.m_cards, sizeof(Card)*52)
FAILURE: 1 out of 1 tests failed (1 failures).

Answer (score 0):

A little tweaking and it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
private:
    int m_face;
    char m_suit;
public:
    Card(int _face = 2 , char _suit = 3)
    {
        m_face = _face;
        m_suit = _suit;
    }
    ~Card(){}
    int GetFace() const { return m_face; }
    char GetSuit() const { return m_suit; }

    void SetFace(int _face) { m_face = _face; }
    void SetSuit(char _suit) { m_suit = _suit; }
    void Show() const
    {
        if (m_face == 11)
            cout << " J " << m_suit << endl;
        else if (m_face == 12)
            cout << " Q " << m_suit << endl;
        else if (m_face == 13)
            cout << " K " << m_suit << endl;
        else if (m_face == 14)
            cout << " A " << m_suit << endl;
        else
            cout << m_face << m_suit << endl;
    }
};
class Deck
{
private:
    Card m_cards[52];
    int current;
public:
    Deck() { Initialize(); }
    void Initialize()
    {
        current = 51;
        int count = 0;
        char Suits[] = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) //Suits
        {

            for (int F = 2; F <= 14; ++F) //faces
            {
                m_cards[count++].SetSuit(Suits[i]);
                m_cards[count++].SetFace(F);

            }
        }
    }
    void Shuffle() { std::random_shuffle(m_cards, m_cards + current + 1); }
    bool Draw(Card& _card)
    {
        if (IsEmpty()) return false;
        _card = m_cards[current--];
        return true;
    }
    void Clear() { current = -1; }
    bool IsEmpty() const { return current < 0; }
};
int main()
{
    Deck deck;
    while(!deck.IsEmpty())
    {
        Card c;
        deck.Draw(c);
        c.Show();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i know but I cant use this, This is a turn in project and I cant use this i get errors, thanks though for taking the time

Comment: I dont get any errors with the above code. What exactly do you want? Because i dont see any problem with your `initialize` that has not already been highlighted by @Jos Bosmas

Comment: I edited the code. Made a little changes in `initialize`. Is this what you expect? I also realized you write `class` with upper case c.